# Popular answers effect on Votes and Q/A reading habits

Tags: discussion, voting

I recently was struggling with a somewhat advanced build configuration, and [I posted this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22040250/grunt-alter-template-created-from-another-task) seeking community help on the "right way" to achieve the result I was looking for. Initially, I received an upvote, but then a bunch of down-votes, and I never was able to get anyone to tell me why.

Like any experienced SO user, I usually put a decent amount of thought to my question, so the downvotes were very perplexing, and worse... I was never able to get any of the down-voters to explain their reason for the downvote.  I even asked several experienced friends (experts themselves in the related field), and they couldn't tell me anything that might cause them to do the same.

So after some thought, I began to wonder if the only given answer was influencing voters. I have a habit of reading the title of a question, and then skipping ahead to the answer before taking the time to read a moderate length question.  When I go back to read the question, it's often in context of the popular answer(s).

To me, this seems like a natural tendency for a programmer. We all interpret a question a slightly different way, and since we're stereotypically lazy, I'm thinking we do this so that we don't have to burn brain fuel putting a few things together before/while reading the original question.

With that in mind... I wonder if these (below) are habits you have, or think others have, and more importantly, if there's a direct correlation to the 2.

1. Do you ever read popular/accepted answers before fully reading a moderate/long question
2. Do you think a viewer may be influenced to upvote/downvote a question based on the content of a popular/accepted answer

Comment: I'm not familiar with Grunt but I wouldn't downvote that question...I did gave it a minor edit to make sure the question pops out...

Comment: The feature-request of forcing down-voters to leave a comment has been raised many times before. And please don't ask three questions at once.

Comment: Watch out with that last suggestion - we've had the forced-explanations discussion to death, and to resurrection, and to death again.

Comment: related to #3: [Encouraging people to explain downvotes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes)

Comment: I'm removing the last item.  @EnergyNumbers the actual question I'm asking if there's a direct correlation for #1 & #2.  After removing the 3rd bullet, I'm hoping I've addressed your concern? Thanks everyone for pointing out that bit about my 3rd item.

Comment: This seems really weird - I don't know grunt but this looks like a decent question. Not sure what happened here, it's definitely not the norm.

Comment: Eh... I put that single instance behind me. Still scratch my head, but sometimes it's just what happens around here.  I'm more curious about reading habits and correlation to votes as a result though, hence the question here on meta.

Comment: Reading the answers first makes sense - if there's already a good one I might skip the question altogether or at least read it fast, but if the answers are all very short and inconclusive, I'll try to read the question with more care and maybe attempt to answer myself.

Comment: Although I also don't understand the downvotes I would say the comment is a little forceful. Asking why the downvotes is fine but telling people there is no reason to downvote is only likely to encourage more downvotes

Comment: @leeor you should put that comment as an answer. Thank you for responding to the question. Richard, I did wonder that at one point, thx for the thought. Any thoughts on this question?  Note: Should I remove the link to the SO question?  Seems more people are focusing on that than the point of this post.

Answer (score 3):

I'll try to expand my comment a little:

I also have a tendency to sometime read the answers first - if there's already a good answer I might skip the question altogether or at least read it fast, because I probably won't have anything significant to add over that (in some of the tags I could tell that right away according to the author of that answer - some power users may on occasion get it wrong, but the odds of that are slim). I'll usually try to add another answer in such cases only if the topic is one of my fields of expertise, or if I get an interesting suggestion that wasn't covered.
If, on the other hand, the answers are all very short and inconclusive, I'll try to read the question with more care for the details, and maybe attempt to answer myself.

Another reason to read answers first, is that they're usually more organized and easy to comprehend than the question itself. This is usually the case with questions by low reputation points users - the answer would often explain the problem better than the question itself.

Having said all that, it's important to notice that there's a potential bias here - reading the answer first could affect your judgment of the problem, and "close your mind" to alternatives you may have come up with. Sometimes it's not important ("dude, you have a typo"), but sometimes it may be ("you can try this algorithm..."). Either way it's a risk you're taking, although I had cases where it was some other answer that triggered my thought process, giving me an idea that was using a completely different approach. Maybe there's some gut feeling like "Ha, this guy is wrong!" that gives you an incentive to answer, whatever works best for you.

Now, as for the voting effect - I think there's indeed a general effect of "vote spilling" coming from good posts. That is - if a question is highly voted, the answers (especially the accepted one), are likely to get more votes than otherwise. People are probably thinking that such a good question must be complicated and therefore any reasonably sensible answer must be really smart. In the same sense - a good answer spills over to the question, maybe as a token of gratitude for paving the road for the great answer (or just out of general goodwill and euphoria having just read a really mind blowing explanation - you get these occasionally in Stack Overflow). Other answers could also get that effect (maybe a pity vote for having to compete with the super-answer).

On the other hand, downvote spilling is slightly more rare, first of all because downvotes are more rare, but also because when an answer is wrong, I guess people understand it doesn't reflect on the question (although there could be a case where a bad answer is caused by an ambiguous or unclear question, which should reflect on its voting). The other way around - downvoted questions spilling to answers - are cases when someone asks a lazy question (homework solution and suchlike), people tell him off, and then someone posts a full answer. Some users see this as setting a bad example and attracting bad questions to the site, and they may downvote the answer accordingly.

Again, I'd like to say that all these "spilling" effects are not good. A post should be judged according to its content alone. However, people are not robots, and you should accept some drifts due to context.